# Cannot shutdown/reboot windows 7 when session is locked

Tags: windows, windows-7

I'm running a Windows 7 in a KVM virtual machine on my laptop.

When there is no user logged in or if I'm logged in but the session is not locked, I can ask Windows to shutdown or reboot directly from the host (ACPI signal?).

But when the session is locked, nothing is happening anymore.

This is quite annoying because if I forget to shutdown the VM (or unlock the session) before shutting down the host, the VM is just killed.

I'm looking for a way to make Windows behave the same way as when the session is unlocked. An idea?

Edit: It's Windows 7 enterprise and it's linked to an AD, but I'm never connecting to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you discovered, when the session is locked Windows does **not** respond to ACPI events. However, you **can** shutdown the machine via WMI and other APIs.

As a side note, I did some testing on how Windows responds to ACPI shutdown event. You can find more [here](http://www.ilsistemista.net/index.php/virtualization/49-kvm-windows-virtual-machines-and-acpi-unattended-shudown-a-recap.html)

Answer (score -1):

Having looked around a bit, it appears there is unfortunately no way to enable reboot/shutdown from the start menu in a remote session in Windows 7, even through group policies :( I guess Windows 7 is designed for a "dumber" user on average, considering Server 2008 is not gimped in this way :) I guess my main method will be to press Ctrl-Alt-End (remote equivalent to Ctrl-Alt-Del) and then use the shutdown options from that dialog.